# Payflow Pro Reference Transactin is not working for test account

Tags: php, paypal, transactions

I want to integrate Payflow pro reference transaction (Credit card) in my cart. I am using payflow manager test account and enabled reference transactions to "Yes" in manage security tab.

I could successfully transfer test payment first time, this is my response - Array ( [RESULT] => 0 [PNREF] => A70A7EB1773A [RESPMSG] => Approved [AUTHCODE] => 928PNI [AVSADDR] => X [AVSZIP] => X [CVV2MATCH] => Y [HOSTCODE] => A [PROCAVS] => U [PROCCVV2] => M [VISACARDLEVEL] => 12 [IAVS] => X [PREFPSMSG] => No Rules Triggered [POSTFPSMSG] => No Rules Triggered )

But when I try to do reference transactions, i am getting below response - Array ( [RESULT] => 23 [PNREF] => A1008A6A9700 [RESPMSG] => Invalid account number ), I am using same PNREF num as ORIGID and successfully completed payment at initial time. Then why it is showing "Invalid account number" ?

Below arguments I have used for reference transaction - $nvpstr = "TRXTYPE=S&TENDER=C&PWD=an****&PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=an****&USER=an****&ORIGID=A70A7EB1773A&AMT=2.00";

Do we need to call paypal team to enable reference transaction for TEST ACCOUNT also ? Please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not passing the "TRXTYPE=S" along with the other parameters. Even though in your above request you have mentioned "TRXTYPE=S" but still I believe somehow it is not being sent to the PayPal .

Comment: No , I send TRXTYPE=S through Paypal api